# Vue-Analytics not working (note: I need to change id based on hostname)

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to use vue-analytics, but am not receiving any data (except for when I try it in localhost).

Our situation is unique, in that we have different domains for each customer.  So, the Google Analytics id should change depending on the hostname.

I've set the id to change depending on the window.location.hostname, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Could you please advise where I am going wrong?

Thanks,

Sloan

p.s. - code below...

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueSession from 'vue-session';
import stitcher from './components/stitcher.vue';
import * as auth from '@companyname/auth';
import * as dashboard from '@companyname/dashboard';
// import * as lgc from '@companyname/final-lgc';
import * as tasking from '@companyname/tasking';
import * as help from '@companyname/help';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import notFound from './components/notFound.vue';
import terms from './components/Terms.vue';
import privacy from './components/Privacy.vue';
import permissionDenied from './components/permissionDenied.vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import * as GoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';
import {get} from 'lodash';
import {ready} from '@companyname/interservice';
import VueAnalytics from 'vue-analytics'

import VueQuillEditor from 'vue-quill-editor';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.core.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import abilityPlugin from './config/ability-plugin';
import abilities from './config/abilities';

window.vueGoogleMapsInit();
Vue.use(GoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf',
    libraries: 'places'
  }
});

Vue.use(Router);
Vue.use(VueSession);
Vue.use(VueQuillEditor);
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(abilityPlugin, abilities);

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: dashboard.app,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true },
      children: dashboard.routes()
    },
    {
      path: '/auth',
      component: auth.app,
      children: auth.routerConfig(),
      meta: {featureName: 'auth'}
    },
    /*
    {
      path: '/lgc',
      name: 'lgc',
      component: lgc.app,
      meta: {requiresAuth: true, featureFlag: {feature: 'lgc', description: 'LGC'}}
    },
    */
    {
      path: '/tasking',
      component: tasking.app,
      meta: {requiresAuth: true, featureName: 'tasking'},
      children: tasking.routes()
    },
    {
      path: '/assignment/task/:taskId',
      redirect: to => '/tasking' + to.path,
      props: true
    },
    {
      path: '/answers/task/:taskId',
      redirect: to => '/tasking' + to.path
    },
    {
      path: '/help',
      name: 'help',
      component: help.app,
      children: help.routes()
    },
    {
      path: '/terms',
      name: 'terms',
      component: terms
    },
    {
      path: '/privacy',
      name: 'privacy',
      component: privacy
    },
    {
      path: '/permissiondenied',
      name: 'permissiondenied',
      component: permissionDenied
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      component: notFound
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    let redirectPath;
    const loggedIn = await ready;
    const user = loggedIn.user || null;
    const featureFlag = get(to, 'meta.featureFlag.feature');
    if (!loggedIn) {
      if (localStorage.loggedOut && localStorage.loggedOut === 'true') {
        redirectPath = '/';
      } else {
        redirectPath = to.fullPath;
      }
      localStorage.loggedOut = 'done';
      next({
        path: '/auth',
        query: { redirect: redirectPath }
      });
    } else if (featureFlag) {
      const allowed = get(user, `featureFlags.${featureFlag}`);
      const description = get(to, 'meta.featureFlag.description');
      const fullPath = to.fullPath;
      if (allowed) {
        next();
      } else {
        next({
          path: '/permissiondenied',
          query: { description, fullPath }
        });
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next(); // make sure to always call next()!
  }
});

function getClientId(environment) {
  let uaId;
  switch (environment) {
    case 'customer1.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-1';
      break;
    case 'customer2.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-2';
      break;
    case 'customer3.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-3';
      break;
    case 'customer4.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-4';
      break;
    case 'customer5.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-5';
      break;
    case 'customer6.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-6';
      break;
    case 'customer7.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-7';
      break;
    case 'customer8.companysite.com':
      uaId = 'UA‌-123456789-8';
      break;
    case 'localhost':
      uaId = 'UA-123456789-9';
      break;
    default:
      uaId = 'no_id';
      break;
  }
  console.log('id', uaId);
  return uaId;
}

let clientID = getClientId(window.location.hostname);

if (clientID !== 'no_id') {
  Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
    id: clientID,
    router
  });
}

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(stitcher)
});
```

Comment: Have you `console.log`ged out the value of `clientID` in various spots to make sure it's correct?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I actually added the debugger and was able to see that the id was not in the correct format.  It works now.  Thanks!